# Java reflection calling a method from same context

Tags: java, performance, reflection

I have spend the last 1 or 2 hours diving into Java reflection.
I think i'm starting to have a proper understanding.

I could not however find a few answers I was looking for.

What I came to understand is that reflection suffers a big(biggest?) performance hit from class lookups.

I have 2 questions.

How can you call a method from within the current context(is it even possible?)?
And will the performance hit from class lookups be canceled out when calling within the current context?

for example:

```
class User {
   private String name;

   public getName(){ return name; }
   public setName(String name){ this.name = name; }

   public void doSomething() {
       //some random stuff
       //I would like this method to invoke randomMethod();
       //Since it is within the same context(this)
       //Will this reduce the performance cost?

       //Please assume from my goals that I will ALWAYS know the name of the method i                  want to call.
      //So I wont need to loop through all available methods.

   }

   public void randomMethod() {

   }
}
```

Im trying to achieve some kind of dispatcher.
For example for web development in Java.

Im not interested in frameworks etc.

So if a user enters an url http://www.hiurl.com/home/index

Where home is the controller and index the action(the method name to be called by reflection).

If you have good arguments why to absolutely avoid this apart from the many chances of failing, please let me know aswell.

I hope my question is clear.
Thanks for taking the time to read and I look forward to read your replies.

Comment: What do you mean by 'context', and 'current context'?

Comment: The current instance of the User class. For example if the randomMethod() method is called using this.randomMethod(), the this keyword refers to the current user instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately one cannot optimize subsequent method calls via reflection even if all of them are executed on the same instance. The reason for this basically is the signature of reflection methods for invocation:

```
// in java.lang.reflect.Method
Object invoke(Object instance, Object... args);

// in java.lang.reflect.Field
Object get(Object instance)
```

The only thing one can do to optimize calls using reflection is to store references to `Method`, `Field`, `Constructor` etc. in order to avoid costly lookups each invocation e.g:

```
public class User {

    public void methodToBeCalledUsingReflection() {
        // some logic
    }

    public void invocationWithPerformanceHit() {
        // lookup of Method instance - costly operation!
        Method method = User.class.getMethod("methodToBeCalledUsingReflection");
        // actual invocation of method
        method.invoke(this);
    }

    public void invocationWithoutPerformanceHit() {
        // only actual invocation of method
        method.invoke(this);
    }

    // moving Method instance to static field which is initialized (looked up) only once
    public static final Method method = getMethodReference("methodToBeCalledUsingReflection");

    private static Method getMethodReference(String methodName) {
        try {
            return User.class.getMethod(methodName);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Besides that, I would recommend using Reflection only if it's highly justified since it hampers performance, is less typesafe and has some other drawbacks. If one can go without Reflection, one should not use it.

Comment: First off all, thanks for your great reply. I have one question though. I just found out within the user class you get use getClass().getMethod();  I assume getClass wont do a new full class lookup. Does it? Will this have no effect on performance? Aside the question, your post is very helpfull. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, there are 3 possibilities to get instance of a `Class`: 1. `SomeClass.class` - the fastest way, no need to store references, since it's literal 2. `someInstance.getClass()` - I guess it's the same or very close to 1st 3. `Class.forName("com.some.package.SomeClass")` - definitely costly operation because it performs lookup - here it's essential to store reference to `Class` instance.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly you want to execute different parts of code for a given string.

i think you should avoid reflection if there is a more "regular" way doing this, simply because of better code readability.

Think of using something like the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Should work well in your case.

Comment: You are right, I do want to execute code given a string. Im trying to create a dispatcher. For example for an MVC application. I will read the strategy wiki. Always interested in learning patterns. Thanks.

Comment: Totally agree with resTive about using strategy pattern for such tasks

Comment: as an additional information: to create the different strategies use the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to split up execution logic and object creation.

Comment: I understand that other patterns might be more usefull in this usecase. However my study today is about reflection and how to achieve certain things. Thanks though. Learning a ne wpattern is always a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should absolutely not worry about performance if all you are doing is dispatching to the controller method. The whole issue of the slowness of reflection is when you are comparing 1ns needed to directly call a method with maybe 100ns needed for lookup + invocation. BTW I would prefer reflection to the Strategy pattern, but those two are indeed quite close, so it's your call.

Comment: In this specific case I would prefer reflection aswell. Thanks for clarification. I will stick to reflection in the end. But im happy to learn about other usefull patterns to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference from what kind of context you are going to invoke you method, in all cases you are doing it in the same manner. You need to pass 'this' object to invoke method.

Look at: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/CallamethoddynamicallyReflection.htm